# What is repeat mode of TextSurface?

Tags: android, repeat

I'm using [Github](https://github.com/elevenetc/TextSurface) project named **TextSurface** and in it's example by pressing a button an effect or animation played of that specific text.

I'm wondering how to put it(that effect) in infinite loop state or simply it's play by itself without pressing that button(loop state).

Here is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextSurface textSurface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textSurface = (TextSurface) findViewById(R.id.text_surface);

        textSurface.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                show();
            }
        }, 1000);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void show() {
        textSurface.reset();
        CookieThumperSample.play(textSurface, getAssets());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the owner of the code mentioned above update his/her project.
Here is the detail:

https://github.com/elevenetc/TextSurface/commit/6ecd2d01126fd7277fa427ab9453ab564536bbd9?diff=unified

Answer (score 1):

According to @SDG69 answer and github commeit you can user `new Loop()` method for looping the animation. forexample :

```
textSurface.play(
            new Loop(
                    ShapeReveal.create(textDaai, 750, SideCut.show(Side.LEFT), false),
                    new Parallel(ShapeReveal.create(textDaai, 600, SideCut.hide(Side.LEFT), false), new Sequential(Delay.duration(300), ShapeReveal.create(textDaai, 600, SideCut.show(Side.LEFT), false))),
                    new Parallel(new TransSurface(500, textBraAnies, Pivot.CENTER), ShapeReveal.create(textBraAnies, 1300, SideCut.show(Side.LEFT), false)),
                    Delay.duration(1000),
                    new Parallel(new TransSurface(750, textFokkenGamBra, Pivot.CENTER), Slide.showFrom(Side.LEFT, textFokkenGamBra, 750), ChangeColor.to(textFokkenGamBra, 750, Color.WHITE)),
                    Delay.duration(800)));
```